# Como puedo saber cuando una barra de progreso(Hecha en HTML) se llena completamente con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, progressbar

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que nesecito subir archivos a un servidor, ya hice todo, pero nesecito saber como ejecutar un alert cuando la barra de progreso se llene(basicamente detectar cuando la barra de progreso llegue el 100%)

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Parte del codigo:

Barra

```
 <progress id="img-upload-bar" value="0" max="100" style="width: 100%">   </progress>
```

Para que la barra de progreso aumente su valor

```
const res = await axios.post(CLOUDINARY_URL, formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    onUploadProgress(e){
        console.log(Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total));
        const progress = (e.loaded * 100) / e.total;
        imageUploadbar.setAttribute('value', progress);
    }
    
})
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu código, por favor? Sin código será muy poca la ayuda que podrás obtener

Comment: el unico codigo que pueda servir de algo seria el de la barra de progreso, te lo doy?

Answer (score 2):

1.- Puedes simplemente poner el alert inmediatamente después de que realizas la subida al servidor ejemplo:

```
const res = await axios.post(CLOUDINARY_URL, formData, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    onUploadProgress(e){
        console.log(Math.round((e.loaded * 100) / e.total));
        const progress = (e.loaded * 100) / e.total;
        imageUploadbar.setAttribute('value', progress);
    }
    
})

alert("Archivo subido correctamente");
```

El alert se ejecutará una vez que termine todo lo anterior gracias a `async` `await`

Aunque lo ideal sería evaluar tu respuesta ejemplo:

```
if(res.status === 200){
 alert('Archivo subido correctamente');
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, lo probare :)

Comment: @Lina109 agregue una nueva línea de código a mi respuesta para afinar mejor tu código.